# Error adding Contract pallet to runtime

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract

I have followed [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/), which adds the Contracts pallet to a Substrate runtime, and get the following error:

```
amit@amit-Swift-SF315-41:~/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template$ cargo check -p node-template-runtime
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
error: failed to get `pallet-contracts` as a dependency of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `pallet-contracts`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=latest

Caused by:
  failed to find tag `latest`

Caused by:
  reference 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/latest' not found; class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of your pallet contracts dependencies are wrong (I am assuming you are using the current substrate-node-template).

Below are the needed dependencies:

```
pallet-contracts = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23", default-features = false }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23", default-features = false }
pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23", default-features = false }
```

I have a detailed blog on this: http://tinyurl.com/yckd2axc